# Web cache system on server side

Tags: caching, liferay, server-side, squid

suppose we have a complex web application composed of more systems (Liferay etc).

I would like to include into my architecture also a web cache system for caching  of public contents (for example as resulting from Liferay or other internal service).

I am looking at **`Squid`**. Can you suggest to me also other technologies such as `squid`?

Are there some standard ways to apply a cache also on private content (user registred)?

How do I handle dynamic pages (such as a jsp with some fragments of other public and private (only registered users)?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at squid, you're looking at HTTP level caching. Thus, whenever someone is signed in to your system, you'll have to work around the cache: Once the user name appears on the page or some permissions are checked for content access, you can't generically cache on HTTP level other than in the user's browser (or for external media, like CSS, images).

For Liferay you can look at Liferay's CDN capabilities: You can configure a CDN (Content Delivery Network) which addresses external hosts that work like reverse proxies - these would serve the cachable content while the portal serves the pages (esp. for logged in users)

Liferay also will signal upstream caches that anonymously accessed pages are cacheable if ALL of their content signals that it's cacheable. This is automatic. I assume you're not asking about what you need to do in single portlets to signal that their content is cacheable.

You should ask yourself, what problem you want to solve (as you only mention this one technology, HTTP level caches). Did you do a performance tuning where this was identified as the biggest bottleneck? Are most of your users anonymous or logged in? As you're explicitly asking for caching of dynamic content: This typically can't be done, or only in a limited way - e.g. only through composing the pages from static content that generates AJAX code, fetching the real content.